# Java Spring set custom entity resolver for web service xsd parser

Tags: java, spring, soap, xsd, wsdl

When publishing wsdl (...) Spring invokes SchemaLoaderUtils.loadSchema with the passed xsd schema where it creates XMLReader and SchemaFactory.
Is there any way for somehow interfeiring in this process to set custom EntityResolver?

Reason: the default entity resolver can not resolve xsd:imports to classpath resources, but I need it to. The xsd file to be imported is located in another jar file. So it fails to publish wsdl.